# How to disable the fields in settings in iphone based on other setting?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

On an iPhone, when you go to Settings > Nike + iPod, in the app's settings, when you set Nike+iPod to off, it disables the rest of the settings. How do I do that?
How do I disable the other setting depending on the value selected in ToggleSwitchSpecifier?
Can we do it using Setting.Bundle? Or do we have to use preference.Bundle?
Can we use Preference.Bundle for that? If yes, how?

Sent me the documents related to preference.Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Preference.Bundle is not available for AppStore apps, you can only use that for jailbroken based apps.

Also Preference.Bundle is the only way to get this functionality you are looking for, because only that allows you to run code. See this blog post for more details: http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/08/12/creating-a-preferencebundle-for-the-iphone/